# Help interpreting a chain of Kanji from manga

Tags: translation, meaning, interpretation

me and my buddies are reading a novel based on the manga series "Bleach." We are trying to interpret the name of a character's power-up

> 逆様邪八宝塞 (sakashima, yokoshima, Hatsubou, fusagari)

The character's powers are "reversal" based.

We are debating over these questions -

1) Does 塞 describe 八宝 or act as a noun?.
2) Does 邪 affect 逆様 or 八宝?

My interpretation is-

> eight treasure obstruction of reversed evil

My buddy thinks it's more likely-

> Eight obstructed treasures of evil reversal.

But if we go with my buddy's interpretation, why isn't 塞 placed in front of 八宝 instead? Same with 邪 and 逆様. Doesn't the object being described come after the descriptor in Japanese?

Comment: Where did you get the reading `sakashima`? (https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E9%80%86%E6%A7%98&oq=%E9%80%86%E6%A7%98&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.391j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the correct reading of 八宝塞 is not "hatsubou fusagari" but "happou-fusagari". It seems like a clear play on the common expression 八方塞, also pronounced "happou-fusagari", which means "nowhere to run" (literally "blocked from all eight directions").

As for why 方 "directions" in the original expression has been replaced with 宝 "treasures" here, it's difficult to say for sure without knowing more about the context of this ability.